# difference between resolve and onFulfilled

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between

`resolve` and `onFulfilled` in javascript promises ?

Similarly,  what is the difference between

`reject` and `onRejected` ?
In simple words, I would just ask how does onsuccess callback of Promise.then(onsuccess, onreject) differs from Promise.resolve ()?

I am reading Javascript with Promises by Daniel Parker.
The book has mentioned both of them but I have not realized the difference between two yet.

While describing then in promises:

> promise.then
>
> promise.then([onFulfilled], [onRejected]) returns promise
>
> The promise.then() method accepts an onFulfilled callback and an
>   onRejected
>       callback. People generally register onRejected callbacks using promise.catch()
>       instead of passing a second argument to then . The function then returns a promise that is resolved by the return value of the
>       onFulfilled or onRejected callback. Any error thrown inside the callback rejects the new promise with that error.

Also,

**Promise.resolve**

> Promise.resolve([value|promise]) returns promise The Promise.resolve()
>   function is a convenience function for creating a promise that is
>   already resolved with a given value. If you pass a promise as the
>   argument to Promise.resolve(), the new promise is bound to the promise
>   you provided and it will be fulfilled or rejected accordingly.

Code:

```
function settled(promises) {
 var alwaysFulfilled = promises.map(function (p) {
 return p.then(
 function onFulfilled(value) {
 return { state: 'fulfilled', value: value };
 },
 function onRejected(reason) {

 return { state: 'rejected', reason: reason };
 }
 );
 });
 return Promise.all(alwaysFulfilled);
}
};
```

Comment: can you show what you mean in some code

Comment: I thought that's what you were talking about - I'm not sure how you can confuse `Promise.resolve()` with the callback functions in `promise.then` - the descriptions you posted in the updated question are quite clear what each is

Comment: @JaromandaX: I still am actually. The doubt may sound absurd to you but what i am not able to get is how does onFulfilled i.e success callback in promise.then differs from Promise.resolve ?

Comment: The MDN documentation also doubles as a nice tutorial - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#Return_value

Answer (score 2):

simply put

when a promise is resolved any current or future onFullfilled functions will be called with the parameter to that function being the value of the resolve function

similarly with reject/onRejected